# Поддерживает ли Mac OS OpenGL 3.3?

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, macos

Пишу приложение на c++ в XCode. Возникли проблемы с шейдерами. Пишет, что версия 330 не поддерживается. Для проверки написал это:

```
unsigned int major = glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR);
unsigned int minor = glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR);

std::cerr << "OpenGL shader version: " << major << "." << minor << std::endl;
std::cerr << "OpenGL version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
```

В обоих случаях пишет версию 2.1, а мне нужна 3.3

Вот код **Window.cpp** с инициализацией glfw

```
#include <iostream>
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "Window.h"
#include <stdio.h>

GLFWwindow* Window::window;
int Window::width = 0;
int Window::height = 0;

int Window::initialize(int width, int height, const char* title){
    if(!glfwInit()){
        std::cerr << "Error: failed init glfw" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //print glfw errors
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (window == nullptr){
        std::cerr << "Failed to create GLFW Window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 2);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    std::cout << "This is Mac" << std::endl;
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

#endif
    //OpenGL version
    unsigned int major = glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR);
    unsigned int minor = glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR);

    std::cerr << "OpenGL shader version: " << major << "." << minor << std::endl;

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    std::cerr << "OpenGL version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;


    glViewport(0,0, width, height);

    Window::width = width;
    Window::height = height;
    return 0;
}

void Window::error_callback(int error, const char* description){
    //error callback
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", description);
}

void Window::setCursorMode(int mode){
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, mode);
}

void Window::terminate(){
    glfwTerminate();
}

bool Window::isShouldClose(){
    return glfwWindowShouldClose(window);
}

void Window::setShouldClose(bool flag){
    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, flag);
}

void Window::swapBuffers(){
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
```

вершинный шейдер:
**main.glslv**

```
#version 150 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 v_position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 v_texCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec4 v_light;

out vec4 a_color;
out vec2 a_texCoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 projview;

void main(){
    vec4 position = projview * model * vec4(v_position, 1.0);
    a_color = vec4(v_light.r,v_light.g,v_light.b,1.0f);
    a_texCoord = v_texCoord;
    a_color.rgb += v_light.a;
    a_color.rgb *= 1.0-position.z*0.0025;
    //a_color.rgb = pow(a_color.rgb, vec3(1.0/0.7));
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

Фрагментный шейдер: **main.glslf**

```
#version 150 core

in vec4 a_color;
in vec2 a_texCoord;
out vec4 f_color;

uniform sampler2D u_texture0;

void main(){
    vec4 tex_color = texture(u_texture0, a_texCoord);
    if (tex_color.a < 0.5)
        discard;
    f_color = a_color * tex_color;
}
```

Ошибки:
SHADER::VERTEX: compilation failed
ERROR: 0:3: Invalid use of layout 'location'
ERROR: 0:4: Invalid use of layout 'location'
ERROR: 0:5: Invalid use of layout 'location'
ERROR: 0:6: Invalid use of layout 'location'
ERROR: 0:15: Use of undeclared identifier 'v_position'
ERROR: 0:16: Use of undeclared identifier 'v_light'
ERROR: 0:16: Use of undeclared identifier 'v_light'
ERROR: 0:16: Use of undeclared identifier 'v_light'
ERROR: 0:17: Use of undeclared identifier 'v_texCoord'
ERROR: 0:18: Use of undeclared identifier 'v_light'
ERROR: 0:19:
failed to load shader
Program ended with exit code: 1

У меня MacBook Pro 13 mid2018, Intel Iris Plus Graphics 655, macOS Mojave 10.14.16, Xcode 10.3. Возможно ли обновить до OpenGL 3.3?

Comment: Если память не изменяет, на маке надо использовать версию 3.2, и контекст создавать с флагом `SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_FLAG`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat извиняюсь, если что то не понимаю, но возможно ли сделать это через glfw? Вы предлагаете использовать sdl?

Comment: Пардон, библиотеку перепутал. В GLFW есть эквивалент: https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT_hint

Comment: @HolyBlackCat в документации glfw написано, что для macOS необходимо установить параметры GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT и GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE. Я поставил GLFW_TRUE и GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE. Нужного результата не добился. По-прежнему версия 2.1. Заменил код в теме на актуальный, чтобы было понятнее

Comment: Хинты надо ставить до создания окна. Еще, поменяйте версию шейдеров на 150.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat сейчас используется версия openGL 4.1. Теперь появились ошибки компиляции шейдера, как я понял, GLSL 150 не поддерживает функции, которые я там вызываю. Почему с OpenGL 4.1 работает GLSL 150 и не работает 410? Как заставить его использовать шейдеры версии 410?